# Need to use class and ids of header in wp_nav_menu

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am converting my HTML site to WordPress, stuck on the menu. I am creating the the menu with wp_nav_menu and need to access all the ids and classes so my header remains the same:

**Header code:**

```
<div class="menu-main-menu-container"><ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-529" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-63 current_page_item menu-item-529"><a href="./" aria-current="page">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-721" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-721"><a href="./how-does-pawn-work/">How Does a Pawn Loan Work?</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-728" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-728"><a href="./contact-us/">Contact Us</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-720" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-720"><a href="./jewelry/">Jewelry</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-727" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-727"><a href="./car-audio-and-accessories/">Car Audio and Accessories</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-724" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-724"><a href="./consumer-electronics/">Consumer Electronics</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-726" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-726"><a href="./tools/">Tools</a></li>
</ul></div>     </div>
```

**So far I have accessed this:**

```
<?php
            wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'=>'primary-menu'
            ,'menu_class'=>'menu-main-menu-container'
            ))
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to below code:

```
wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'=>'primary-menu',
        'menu'                 => '',
        'container'            => 'div',
        'container_class'      => 'menu-main-menu-container',
        'container_id'         => '',
        'container_aria_label' => '',
        'menu_class'           => 'menu',
        'menu_id'              => 'menu-main-menu',
        'echo'                 => true,
        'fallback_cb'          => 'wp_page_menu',
        'before'               => '',
        'after'                => '',
        'link_before'          => '',
        'link_after'           => '',
        'items_wrap'           => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
        'item_spacing'         => 'preserve',
        'depth'                => 0,
        'walker'               => '',
        'theme_location'       => '',
));
```